# AngularJS POST operations always pass ID of zero; results in 405 method not allowed

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, angular2-routing

This question relates to another post I made a few weeks go, which is here: [Web API Routing - Overloaded GET method causes 405 Method Not Allowed for other verbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48525537/web-api-routing-overloaded-get-method-causes-405-method-not-allowed-for-other)

I realized what the problem was there but it is a bit complex so I created this separate question hoping someone can provide a solution.

I have a Web API application that is called by both an AngularJS application and an ASP.NET web forms application. I'm having an issue with one API controller in particular, which deals with UserAccounts. It only occurs when the AngularJS application consumes the API; the web forms app doesn't have this problem.

The following operations are supported in the API:

- GET (one, by int "id")
- GET (all)
- DELETE
- POST
- PUT

In the case of this one particular controller also needs to support a GET by string "username" overload. I had to use attribute routing to distinguish this particular operation from the GET by int "id" version.

Here are the method signatures in my API:

```
[HttpDelete]
[ResponseType(typeof(UserAccount))]
[Route("~/api/UserAccounts/{id:int}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteUserAccount(int id)

[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(UserAccount))]
[Route("~/api/UserAccounts/{id:int}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUserAccount(int id)

[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(EnrollmentApiAccountDto))]
[Route("~/api/UserAccounts/{userName}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUserAccount(string userName)

[HttpGet]
[Route("~/api/UserAccounts")]
public IQueryable<UserAccount> GetUserAccounts()

[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(UserAccount))]
[Route("~/api/UserAccounts")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostUserAccount(UserAccount userAccount)

[HttpPut]
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
[Route("~/api/UserAccounts/{id:int}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutUserAccount(int id, UserAccount userAccount)
```

My resource is defined like this in my AngularJS application:

```
var userAccounts = 
    $resource('http://localhost:62415/api/UserAccounts/:id'), { id: '@id' }, {
        create: { method: 'POST' },
        get: { method: 'GET' },
        query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
        remove: { method: 'DELETE' },
        update: { method: 'PUT' }
});
```

In my AngularJS controller, I am using this code:

```
if ($scope.userAccount.id)
   appFactory.userAccounts.update({ id: $scope.userAccount.id }, $scope.userAccount).$promise.then(onSuccess).catch(onError);
else appFactory.userAccounts.create($scope.userAccount).$promise.then(onSuccess).catch(onError);
```

Basically, for a new userAccount record, $scope.userAccount.id is zero and a POST is performed (POST to "api/UserAccounts/0"). The "id" property is assigned a non-zero value when the record is inserted into the database (it is defined as a primary key/identity field). If it is non-zero, we assume that it's an existing record and a PUT is performed so the existing record can be updated.

When I perform a POST in the AngularJS application, I get a response 405 Method Not allowed. I see this in the response when using Fiddler:

```
Allow: DELETE,GET,PUT

{"$id":"1","message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."}
```

The DELETE, GET-one and PUT operations all accept an "id" argument. POST does not and is not listed among the allowed HTTP verbs. So it seems that the presence of an "id" argument is causing the POST to fail.

When I call the API from the web forms application, the route for a POST is always "api/UserAccounts", and there is no "id" argument passed. Because of this, the POST operation always succeeds. Once I realized this, I used Fiddler to re-execute the failed POST operation from the AngularJS app, however this time using the route without the "id" argument. It succeeded.

It should be noted that there are a bunch of other API controllers in this application and passing an "id" of zero for a POST from the AngularJS application doesn't have an adverse affect, even though technically it isn't correct. It only becomes a problem when we have a GET method that accepts a string argument when there is already a GET method that accepts an int argument.

I did attempt to pass an "id" of null for new records in the AngularJS application, but the ModelState validation failed and I received a 400 Bad Request. That property is the primary key in the database so it must have a value.

So my question is, for a POST operation coming from my AngularJS application, how do I omit the "id" value, since it's irrelevant? Can the AngularJS resource specification be changed so the "id" argument is optional for that type of operation, or will I need to have different resource for HTTP verbs that do and do not support the "id" argument?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The ID property value on the UserAccount to be created needs to be set to zero for, but I can still pass a null value in for the ID when making the request. Doing this will not append the ID value to the URL.

```
if ($scope.userAccount.id)
    appFactory.userAccounts.update({ id: $scope.userAccount.id }, $scope.userAccount).$promise.then(onSuccess).catch(onError);
else
    appFactory.userAccounts.create({ id: null }, $scope.userAccount).$promise.then(onSuccess).catch(onError);
```

Fiddler shows the request is being made to api/UserAccounts on the post now instead of api/UserAccounts/0. I've updated all the instances where this is happening and everything is working correctly now.